Phpstorm - how to sync changes with Docker?
I am new to Docker so I am trying to understand some basics.
I have installed a working Magento Docker dev environment and configured PhpStorm according to this guide markshust/docker-magento
The issue is:

When I do changes in PhpStorm those are not reflected inside the docker images (flushed/cleaned cache)

What am I missing ?

In the directory of the docker installation Sites/magento there are some .yaml files (from my understanding those are loaded bybin/start script):

compose.yaml -> main configuration file loading the images in the relative container directories
compose.dev.yaml -> bind the local/host directories to the container that are mostly used for development (es. src/app/...)

The solution is using a volume-bind to mount a host directories into a container directory for hot code deployment.
Solution:
Check witch files/directories are defined in compose.dev.yaml
if the file edited is not part of the list there are 2 options:

permanently add the file/directories to the compose.dev.yaml

Or

use the bin/copytocontainer script to sync the file every time it is modified

